# Activar ventada modal usando combinación de teclas en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema, quiero activar la ventana modal usando la combinación `alt+n`, en este momento se activa con la tecla enter, cuando cambio a la letra `alt` u otra tecla el modal no se activa.

Este es mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

Precione ENTER

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<script>

$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debemos agregar un *listener* al documento, para que escuché el evento *"keydown"* si se produce este, verificamos que se presionó la tecla *alt* mediante `e.altKey` y luego verificamos el *which* de la tecla `n` que sería `78` si es así mostramos la modal.

Como valor adicional si deseará abrir y cerrar la ventana modal con la misma combinación sería de enviarle el parámetro *toggle* en lugar de *show*

```js
document.addEventListener ("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.altKey  &&  e.which === 78) {
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Dev. Joel.